# Oracle SQL Developer Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

T1

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 2 | NA |
| 2 | 8 | 5 | NA |
| 3 | 7 | 4 | NA |

T1

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 9 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 |

I want to select Column D from table T1 based on a match with Table T2, for the following condition
If Column A = Column X or Column B = Column Y and Column C = Column Z then SELECT Column D as 'Y' else 'N'.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((T1.A = T2.X OR T1.B = T2.Y) AND T1.C = T2.Z) THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS D FROM T1,T2
```

In the output I am getting both Y and N for the same rows, I only want to get either Y or N as the Column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t2
                          where t1.a = t2.x or
                                (t1.b = t2.y and t1.c = t2.z)
                         )
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag
from t1;
```

Note:  I might have the parentheses wrong.  Your English statement and sample code have different logic.